# Activity on android

Tags: android

Usually when an `Activity` starts using an `Intent` ,it uses from right to left transitions.i want to start activity that uses from left to right transitions.
How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution. Just use the following method after `startActivity(intent)`.

```
Intent oneIntent=new Intent(swipe.this,swipes.class);
                startActivity(oneIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_in,   R.anim.slide_right_out);
```

NOTE: Be sure to add animation xml files under res/anim folder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/07/android-transistions-slide-in-and-slide.html it is not Activities but at least views sliding.